# User Control Label and Textbox flow from right to left

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

It was pretty tough to think a title for this question so I'll try to make a better job explaining myself here.

I needed to create a dynamic Windows Form so that when checkbox gets checked/unchecked, few input fields appear/disappear. As far as I know FlowLayoutPanel seemed to be the best tool to achieve this. So I created a Custom User Control that included a Label and a Textbox. I designed this new Control in VS2013 desginer view:

[image: The Custom User Control]

Since the text on the label can vary in length it is important that textbox begins only when label has already ended. However the result I get at the moment looks like this:

[image: Custom User Control in action]

The label should read out "ConnField" instead of "ConnFie". I tried adding these items in FlowLayoutPanel but that resulted in label and textbox not lining up correctly. Are there any attributes/properties that should be set in order to get the expected result? Should I use a container that does it all for me?

On a side note, if there are any other methods to dynamically show/hide elements in the fashion I described above I'd be very happy to use those instead.

Comment: I would have put my controls inside a `TableLayoutPanel` and then dropped that TLP in the `FlowLayoutPanel`.  Then you can `AutoSize` everything.  Let the `Dock` property help you out.

Comment: Something is going to have to give.  Either the label needs to be truncated or the textbox needs to move to the right, inevitably causing misalignment.  You can't have it both ways.  Sanest way is to anchor the textbox to the top+right so you can do something about it when you use the control.  And set Label.AutoElllipsis to True for the tough cases.

Comment: In my final solution I made the label size static and then used the method @TaW recommended to properly align textboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For perfect fits you can script the `TextChanged` event(s) to make sure the `TextBox` always sits in place and keeps a nice size as well..

I have placed a `Label` and a `TextBox` into a `Panel` for testing. You will probaly not need or want the `textBox1_TextChanged` event but it was nice for testing..:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = textBox1.Text;   // this is for testing
}

private void label1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Left  = label1.Right + 6;  // <= this is what you need
    textBox1.Width = panel2.Width - label1.Width - 8;   // <= this is nice to have
}
```

Of course your offsets may vary..and obviously the `Label` has `AutoSize = true`

**Edit**

Since you commented on the problem of getting the TextBoxes aligned with each other across rows here are a few thoughts about this problem. As Hans noted, you can't have it all:

- Complete freedom for the Labels' content
- Perfect fits
- And aligned Textboxes

The three goals conflict. So you need to make compromises:

- If you can restrict the content to a fixed maximum, the result will look best
- Sometimes it helps to have a collegue or even a user look at the content to find a shorter way to express the meaning
- Ellipsis or abbreviations may help. I both cases you should set a ToolTip to show the full content
- Another option is to switch to a narrower Font for some Labels
- Instead of one fixed Label size maybe 2 or 3 will help: The look will be a bit jagged but will look a lot better than with completely free sizes.

Comment: I already used this solution and it gave me the result I expected however there was a problem with the textbox alignment. Meaning that textboxes didn't align at all. I am used to coding so that whenever I try to extend the scope of my program I don't have to recode everything that already works. However I haven't worked with GUI creation before and it seems that lot of the stuff (despite VS2013 being an awesome tool to craft basic GUI-s) has to be hardcoded into GUI classes.

Comment: TextBox alignment: Vertical? The Control or the text inside? The v.alignment should not change by itself, so whatever you prepare in the designer should stay as it is..

Comment: I guess I misused the word "alignment" here. What I meant was that I have added 8 of my custom controls to the FLP and since the text in label part of the control is of different length the vertical alignment of textboxes wasn't the same. I corrected that by editing the control and adding static size to label.

Comment: P.S.: I don't know if I should start a new thread or if I can ask it here but I would like to know what should I do in order to get the control.Text property to show in the label part of the Control?

Comment: The UserControl has a TextChanged event; maybe you can use it to assign the Label.Text if that's what you mean.. Also see the notes in my answer!

Comment: Well you know how Labels work. They have .Text property. What I'd like to do is assign .Text property to my UC and make it so that this .Text property is then passed to the Label inside the UC.

Comment: Exactly. Use the TextChanged of the UC event to do that just like I did with the TextBox's TC event in the answer!

Comment: I added a custom property to my custom user control and added getter setter methods to the property. That did the trick. Thanks for all your input.